# Password only protects some sheets in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection

So I have been trying to include a code to protect all the worksheets in my worksheet using VBA, with different properties per sheet. I have been toying with the following code, but for some reason it only protects some sheets with the password and not with others. Please help.

```
Sub ProtegerTodo()



Sheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="Password", _
    UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
    DrawingObjects:=False, _
    Contents:=True, _
    Scenarios:=False, _
    AllowFormattingCells:=False, _
    AllowFormattingColumns:=False, _
    AllowFormattingRows:=False, _
    AllowInsertingColumns:=False, _
    AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
    AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=False, _
    AllowDeletingColumns:=False, _
    AllowDeletingRows:=False, _
    AllowSorting:=False, _
    AllowFiltering:=True, _
    AllowUsingPivotTables:=False

'Allowing selection of locked or unlocked cells
Sheets("Sheet1").EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions

'Allowing selection of unlocked cells only
'Sheets("Sheet1").EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells

'Do not allow selection of any cells
'Sheets("Sheet1").EnableSelection = xlNoSelection

Sheets("Consecutivo de Cirugías").Protect Password:="Password", _
    UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
    DrawingObjects:=False, _
    Contents:=True, _
    Scenarios:=False, _
    AllowFormattingCells:=False, _
    AllowFormattingColumns:=False, _
    AllowFormattingRows:=False, _
    AllowInsertingColumns:=False, _
    AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
    AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=False, _
    AllowDeletingColumns:=False, _
    AllowDeletingRows:=False, _
    AllowSorting:=False, _
    AllowFiltering:=True, _
    AllowUsingPivotTables:=False

'Allowing selection of locked or unlocked cells
Sheets("Consecutivo de Cirugías").EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions

'Allowing selection of unlocked cells only
'Sheets("Sheet1").EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells

'Do not allow selection of any cells
'Sheets("Sheet1").EnableSelection = xlNoSelection

Sheets("Nueva CX").Protect Password:="Password", _
    UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
    DrawingObjects:=False, _
    Contents:=True, _
    Scenarios:=False, _
    AllowFormattingCells:=True, _
    AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
    AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
    AllowInsertingColumns:=False, _
    AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
    AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=False, _
    AllowDeletingColumns:=False, _
    AllowDeletingRows:=False, _
    AllowSorting:=False, _
    AllowFiltering:=True, _
    AllowUsingPivotTables:=False

'Allowing selection of locked or unlocked cells
'Sheets("Nueva CX").EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions

'Allowing selection of unlocked cells only
Sheets("Nueva CX").EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells

'Do not allow selection of any cells
'Sheets("Sheet1").EnableSelection = xlNoSelection

Sheets("Catalogo").Protect Password:="Password", _
    UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
    DrawingObjects:=False, _
    Contents:=True, _
    Scenarios:=False, _
    AllowFormattingCells:=False, _
    AllowFormattingColumns:=False, _
    AllowFormattingRows:=False, _
    AllowInsertingColumns:=False, _
    AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
    AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=False, _
    AllowDeletingColumns:=False, _
    AllowDeletingRows:=False, _
    AllowSorting:=False, _
    AllowFiltering:=True, _
    AllowUsingPivotTables:=False

'Allowing selection of locked or unlocked cells
Sheets("Catalogo").EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions

'Allowing selection of unlocked cells only
'Sheets("Sheet1").EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells

'Do not allow selection of any cells
'Sheets("Sheet1").EnableSelection = xlNoSelection

Sheets("Procedimientos").Protect Password:="Password", _
    UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
    DrawingObjects:=False, _
    Contents:=True, _
    Scenarios:=False, _
    AllowFormattingCells:=False, _
    AllowFormattingColumns:=False, _
    AllowFormattingRows:=False, _
    AllowInsertingColumns:=False, _
    AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
    AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=False, _
    AllowDeletingColumns:=False, _
    AllowDeletingRows:=False, _
    AllowSorting:=False, _
    AllowFiltering:=True, _
    AllowUsingPivotTables:=False

'Allowing selection of locked or unlocked cells
Sheets("Procedimientos").EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions

'Allowing selection of unlocked cells only
'Sheets("Sheet1").EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells

'Do not allow selection of any cells
'Sheets("Sheet1").EnableSelection = xlNoSelection

Sheets("Inventario").Protect Password:="Password", _
    UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
    DrawingObjects:=False, _
    Contents:=True, _
    Scenarios:=False, _
    AllowFormattingCells:=False, _
    AllowFormattingColumns:=False, _
    AllowFormattingRows:=False, _
    AllowInsertingColumns:=False, _
    AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
    AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=False, _
    AllowDeletingColumns:=False, _
    AllowDeletingRows:=False, _
    AllowSorting:=False, _
    AllowFiltering:=True, _
    AllowUsingPivotTables:=False

'Allowing selection of locked or unlocked cells
Sheets("Inventario").EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions

'Allowing selection of unlocked cells only
'Sheets("Sheet1").EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells

'Do not allow selection of any cells
'Sheets("Sheet1").EnableSelection = xlNoSelection

Sheets("Ingreso de material").Protect Password:="Password", _
    UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
    DrawingObjects:=False, _
    Contents:=True, _
    Scenarios:=False, _
    AllowFormattingCells:=True, _
    AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
    AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
    AllowInsertingColumns:=False, _
    AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
    AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=False, _
    AllowDeletingColumns:=False, _
    AllowDeletingRows:=False, _
    AllowSorting:=False, _
    AllowFiltering:=True, _
    AllowUsingPivotTables:=False

'Allowing selection of locked or unlocked cells
Sheets("Ingreso de material").EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions

'Allowing selection of unlocked cells only
'Sheets("Sheet1").EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells

'Do not allow selection of any cells
'Sheets("Sheet1").EnableSelection = xlNoSelection

End Sub
```

Note: I know it is not very efficient, but it should do the trick.

Thank-you beforehand.

Comment: Which sheets work, and which don't? What's the difference in the parameters used in the ones that do and the ones that don't?

Comment: @KenWhite: Thank-you for the quick reply. The diference depends on the users "privileges" so these vary. The sheets that don´t work are "Catalogo", "Procedimientos" and "Ingreso de material". This was up to two minutes ago. I followed up that macro with this one:Sub Unprotect()

Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:="Password"

Comment: @KenWhite: It seemed to do the trick, yet I fear that It might not work again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried your code and it worked on every single sheet.
Try to delete one sheet at a time and remove its protection code so you will find the exact sheet which starts the issue.

Then keep only that sheet and try to protect using code. If it fails, then protect by right clicking the sheet name and you will get the issue reported in UI - sometimes code doesnt report the errors.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I just ran the same thing, but unprotecting everything and it started to work, but I wonder if it is just a temporary fix. Ty for the advice, I´ll try to do that to prevent further issues